# Do I need to Clone repository for adding a custom branch

Tags: git, github, repository, git-branch, gogs

I have downloaded a Zip folder of Master branch from a `gogs` repository and after initializing `git` in that folder, I have added my own branch and made my own changes.

Now my question is, do I have to CLONE the project in order for adding a new branch to the repository on `gogs` or I can simply add my branch using this way (which is downloading zip folder) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a zip archive of a remote Git repository (be it a gogs one, or any other remote hosting service), means downloading a snapshot view of the default HEAD.

There is no history.
The history you have created by initializing a local repository in it, and creating a branch, has no common base with the one from the original remote repository.

If you want to push back your local branch, you need first to:

- clone the repository
- add your local repo as a remote to the official cloned one, and fetch
- create a new branch
- cherry-pick from the fetched branch to the new branch (and you can [cherry-pick in one command a *range* of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309))
- push back the new branch (which will work, since you are pushing from an actual clone)

That is:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repo
cd ..
git clone https://gogs/me/myRepo myClone
cd myClone
git are remote repo ../repo
git fetch repo
git switch -c newBranch
git cherry-pick repo/localBranch~n..repo/localBranch
git push -u origin newBranch
```

In "`repo/localBranch~n`", replace "`n`" by the number of commits you had created in your local branch.